# Magento Cron throws error after upgrade from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.3.10 with php 7.2

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

Upgraded multistore Magento from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.3.10 to be compliance with PHP 7. But now, if I turn on cache for Configuration

https://monosnap.com/file/QcFj8vBFIpp3JhBZtDItE83P01AHNp#

Cron.php throws errors:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:952:"#0 /is/htdocs/wp12986394_SYR3KK36TC/www/magento/online/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(848): Mage_Core_Model_App->throwStoreException()
#1 /is/htdocs/wp12986394_SYR3KK36TC/www/magento/online/app/Mage.php(356): Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore(NULL)
#2 /is/htdocs/wp12986394_SYR3KK36TC/www/magento/online/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Helper/Data.php(47): Mage::getStoreConfig('system/log/enab...')
#3 /is/htdocs/wp12986394_SYR3KK36TC/www/magento/online/app/Mage.php(550): Mage_Log_Helper_Data->__construct()
#4 /is/htdocs/wp12986394_SYR3KK36TC/www/magento/online/app/Mage.php(814): Mage::helper('log')
#5 /is/htdocs/wp12986394_SYR3KK36TC/www/magento/online/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php(234): Mage::log('Warning: simple...', 3)
#6 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/is/htdocs/wp12...', 383, Array)
#7 /is/htdocs/wp12986394_SYR3KK36TC/www/magento/online/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php(383): simplexml_load_string('";s:11:"script_name";s:61:"/is/htdocs/wp12986394_SYR3KK36TC/www/magento/online/index.php";}

Any resolution for this issue?
```

Comment: is php7.2-xml installed?

Comment: Is that libxml for php7.2?

Comment: are you using 7.2 or 7.1, 7.0? if so, just do apt-get install php7.0-xml (whatever your version) if you changed from php5.6 for example, you might not have installed it.

Comment: That is php 7.2

Comment: Ok, `sudo apt-get install php7.2-xml` let me know how you get on :]

Comment: ok, thank you. Let me try that. Will update soon.

Comment: Should I be able to see php7.2-xml via phpinfo() ?  I see libxml, SimpleXML, Domxml installed. Is that all not php7.2-xml related?

Comment: Probably, do you not have shell access then?

Comment: My hoster says XML in version libxml2 2.9.1 is bascically installed with php 7.2. Any other ideas?

Comment: my other idea is invalid xml somewhere, did you change any xml files recently?